# Auto-redirect requests from /dirname to /dirname/

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Could somebody assist me in formulating the following .htaccess rule:

if an incoming request contains a top-level directory path like

```
 www.example.com/dirname
```

automatically convert this to

```
 www.example.com/dirname/
```

but only for the *top level*, so requests to

```
 www.example.com/dirname/subdirname
```

remain untouched.

Do I need mod_rewrite for this, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Why wouldn't he? I could think of a couple of use-cases.

Comment: I need to parse `/dirname/` further in a larger mod_rewrite setup and want to streamline requests so I have less rules to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Alias directive if the amount of directives is small enough. Otherwise you would have to go with mod_rewrite and some simple rules.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Huh? Sorry, I thought I had. Maybe I clicked twice.

Comment: Won't this add a `/` after a GET variable? I think it would make `example.com/dirname?stuff=junk` into `example.com/dirname?stuff=junk/` which may throw off the actual query. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite a URL, you need to use `mod_rewrite`. In this case, I would go with something that looks for anything after the initial `/` that isn't `? . # /` and add a `/` after that. Maybe some other SO's will point out other tokens that I am leaving out.

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/./?//#]+)?$ $1/ [L]
```